# Visual studio extension. Show some string on top of method like CodeLens references

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I try to create a VS2015/2017 extension which would show some information on top of the method. The desired UI is similar to how CodeLens "reference statistics" are shown in C#. This feature will be used when editing source code written in language which does not have CodeLens support.
Can you advice if there is some example of such tweaking of Visual Studio editor already? Any API you would suggest to investigate?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no public-facing CodeLens API for Visual Studio.